# KNN: why is my variable is not defined in python?

Tags: python, data-science, knn

I am working on an assignment and I run into this error. I am using python to perform an KNN on a data set. I pretty sure I defined the variable but it says otherwise. This code is written below.

`

```
import pandas as PD
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mtp

data_set= PD.read_csv('hw6.data.csv.gz')

x= data_set.iloc[:,[2,3]].valuesS
y= data_set.iloc[:, 4].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_train, y_train, y_train= train_test_split(x,y, test_size=.25, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
st_x= StandardScaler()
x_train= st_x.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test= st_x.transform(x_test)
```

`

`

```
import pandas as PD
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mtp

data_set= PD.read_csv('hw6.data.csv.gz')

x= data_set.iloc[:,[2,3]].valuesS
y= data_set.iloc[:, 4].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_train, y_train, y_train= train_test_split(x,y, test_size=.25, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
st_x= StandardScaler()
x_train= st_x.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test= st_x.transform(x_test)
```

`

The error says "x_test" is not defined Pylance (reportUndefinedVarible)

Comment: On this line, you define the variable `x_train` twice: `x_train, x_train, y_train, y_train`. Then on this line, you reference `x_test` before it's defined: `x_test= st_x.transform(x_test)`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.